# Spring converter doesn't convert custom entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to cipher/decipher a dbField using the converter annotation, this is **working on other entities** where the result of the queries (on the repo) are the entity itself. In this case I'm **returning a custom POJO and not the DB entity** and the dbField (private content) is not being converted as it should. Maybe I'm missing something.

The information is being ciphered on the db but I'm getting the ciphered information on the service, so it's not being deciphered.

I've searched the documentation but I couldn't manage to find anything regarding custom queries and converters.

Below you can see the code. Any further information I'm able to provide. Thanks for your time.

**DbEntity**

```
@Entity
public class History {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Convert(converter = CryptoConverter.class)    
    private String privateContent;

    // getters and setters omitted for clarity
}
```

**Converter**

```
@Converter
public class CryptoConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final byte[] KEY = "BLABLAKEY".getBytes();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String clientData) {
        if(isBlank(clientData)){
            return clientData;
        }

        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(c.doFinal(clientData.getBytes()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CryptoException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if(isBlank(dbData)){
            return dbData;
        }

        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return new String(c.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CryptoException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface HistoryRepository extends JpaRepository<History, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT mh.id, mh.privateContent FROM history mh WHERE mh.account=:account")
    List<HistoryDB> getHistory(@Param("account") final Long account);

}
```

**Custom POJO**

```
public interface HistoryDB {

    String getId();

    String getPrivateContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
@Query("SELECT mh.id AS id, mh.privateContent as privateContent FROM history mh WHERE mh.account = :account")
```

Interface:

```
public interface HistoryDB {

    @Value("#{target.id}")
    String getId();

    @Value("#{target.privateContent}")
    String getPrivateContent();

}
```

You do not return target entity from your query but the aliases which may have not been properly mapped to projection interface.

I guess your response looks like the JSON object with all fields having value null. (Correct me if I am wrong).

**UPDATE 1:**

Also there is a possibility to call attribute converter manually from the projection interface via converter's bean exposion:

```
@Component //Singleton proxy instance in application context (no huge impact)
public class CryptoConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {}
```

And then using it`s method from projection:

```
public interface HistoryDB {

    @Value("#{target.id}") // May omit if works without @Value
    String getId();

    @Value("#{@cryptoConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(target.privateContent)}")
    String getPrivateContent();

}
```

Comment: However I am not sure how AttributeConverter will behave in this case. Please let me know if you try this.

Comment: Hey, the current implementation the fields appear correct, they simply doesn't convert the privateContent and I get ciphered information on the JSON. However I will try your suggestion

Comment: Hey, just tested your suggestion and didn't work :(

Comment: Hm, btw, why wouldn't you return the full entity from query and let the projection make it light? `SELECT mh FROM history mh WHERE mh.account = :account`. I understand this query returns all the columns from history table but there is a chance AttributeConverter will be fired in this case. Also there is a third option which will definitely work - using either `ProjectionFactory` (SpelAware) in your service layer or making custom object mapping (kind of dto).

Comment: It's more efficient specifying the fields. If I make a service and call it from the mapper would work as well but I was trying to find a solution handled automatically by the framework.